# Python check list is correclty ordered when same element values order is not guaranteed

Tags: python

So I have two list with ids and scores

```
ids = [1,2,3,5,6,7]
scores = [5., 5. , 4., 3., 2., 1.]
```

When I do an argsort of scores to later index ids the order is not guaranteed when two elements have similar value.

So the argsort for scores can either be:
`[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]` or `[5, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1]`

When i use those index to slide ids then sorted_ids could be

```
sorted_ids = [7,6,5,3,2,1]
or
sorted_ids = [7,6,5,3,1,2]
```

I would like a method that given the scores they were sorted on will say both `sorted_ids` are "equal".

Comment: Are you referring to numpy's argsort, which appears to have a kind='stable' option?

Comment: Is significant slower so i still want to use quicksort, that is out of the question scope.

Comment: That's the first time you've mentioned quicksort. If it's a critical requirement, then it should appear in your question.

Comment: Well at no point in time in the question I ask for another sorting method either, I only ask for an algorithm to check the criteria mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

How about

`sorted(ids, key=lambda id_: (scores[id_], id_))`

This first sorts by score, then sorts by id. This guarantees that the output of the sort will always be the same, as the ids are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Is significant slower so i still want to use quicksort, that is out of the question scope.

Comment: it's not, did you test it

Comment: this has nothing to do with quicksort the algorithm

Comment: you won't find quicker than ths

Comment: Try this code: 

```
import numpy as np
import time
random_list = np.random.randint(90000, size=10000)

start = time.time()
sorted(random_list)
print(time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
np.sort(random_list)
print(time.time() - start)
```

Sorting with numpy is 7-10x times faster....

I would better argsort with numpy scores and use the indexes for ids, this way i cna turn a 1sec request into 100ms and usable in real time.